# how to show dynamically if linkedwithfd select option is yes then other two select option is no in jquery or java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to show dynamically if linkedwithfd select option is yes then other two select option is no in jquery or java script

Linked With FD

```
        <td><select name="LinkedWithFD" style="height: 30px;"id="LinkedWithFD" class="sideinput">

            <option  value='Y'>Yes</option>
            <option value="N">No</option></select></td>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>Linked With CD</td>
        <td>    <select name="LinkedWithCD" style="height: 30px;" id="LinkedWithCD" class="sideinput">

            <option value='Y'>Yes</option>
            <option  value="N">No</option></select></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>    
             <td>Linked With Others</td>

          <td>  <select name="LinkedWithOthers"  style="height: 30px;"id="LinkedWithOthers" class="sideinput">

                <option value='Y'>Yes</option>
                <option value="N">No</option></select></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do it with an `onchange` event in jquery and checking the value of the `select` initially when the page loads like this.

```js
$("#LinkedWithFD").val() == "Y"? $("select").not("#LinkedWithFD").val("N"):$("select").not("#LinkedWithFD").val("Y");

function check(){
$("#LinkedWithFD").val() == "Y"? $("select").not("#LinkedWithFD").val("N"):$("select").not("#LinkedWithFD").val("Y");

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="LinkedWithFD" style="height: 30px;" id="LinkedWithFD" class="sideinput" onchange="check()">

  <option value='Y'>Yes</option>
  <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
<select name="LinkedWithCD" style="height: 30px;" id="LinkedWithCD" class="sideinput">
  <option value='Y'>Yes</option>
  <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
<select name="LinkedWithOthers" style="height: 30px;" id="LinkedWithOthers" class="sideinput">
  <option value='Y'>Yes</option>
  <option value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

**P.S.** Try changing the value of `LinkedWithFD` to see results. If the value of `LinkedWithFD` will be YES other two will be NO and if it is a No other two will be YES. You can modify it according to your requirement